# Android Studio - Hide aar modules dependencies in another aar module

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0, aar

I'm facing a problem while developing a library with Android Studio.

- The concept is to create one aar (MyLib) which is depends on other aar.
  At the end, I want to hide everything from the other aar, and only exposed 'MyLib'.

So I found this tool: 'com.kezong.fat-aar' which give me the ability to create one big fat aar from 'multiple aar'.
Then I have created a ProGuard to only include (-keep) some classes of 'MyLib'.
It works but I can still access to classes defined in the 'multiple aar'.

I've made some online research and I can't find any solution.
Now I wonder if it's even possible to achieve what I want because 'MyLib' should access to the 'multiple aar' (dependencies) but I don't want that the user or client can see them.

Sorry for my bad english...
Do you have any clue or information to help me ?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: If your library module includes other modules as an `implementation` dependency - then anyone using your module will not see the classes from the other modules.

Comment: Yes you're right. But with 'implementation' anyone who use MyLib will have to add all the aar modules at project creation. I want to embed the modules inside MyLib, in order to only add MyLib aar at project creation.

Comment: I understand, I met this problem a few years ago - I thought now nobody uses .aar anymore and instead you offer a compiled dependency. This is an old article but is this what you want: https://blog.blundellapps.co.uk/locally-release-an-android-library-for-jcenter-or-maven-central-inclusion/ here is something more up to date: https://cuttlesoft.com/blog/how-to-publish-an-android-library-to-jcenter/ so then people just add the dependency not all aar's

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look. The only problem I see right now is about using maven.